How can I solve the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' "in a venv. in VS Code?
I am new to programming and working with deep learning networks, so maybe I'm just stupid, but I can't get my PyTorch to work. Not long ago, it did without problem, but then I tried to fix CUDA for GPU acceleration (which did not work), and ever since, my Torch has refused to work. I run the programs in a virtual environment (venv.) in VS Code with Python version 3.11.9, but when I try to verify my Torch with.
import torch

print(torch.__version__)

I only receive the error that:
File "c:\Python\Test\torch_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Python\Test\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module cannot be found. Error loading "C:\Python\Test\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
PS C:\Python\Test>

I have tried to install Torch a million times by now, both inside and outside the venv with pip and pip3 in both the VS Codes terminal and in the command prompt. But everytime I get back, the "Requirement already satisfied". Yet still, the Torch is not working is absent.
When looking through stackoverflow, I find mostly people that have used Conda environments, which I am not familiar with. So if there is a solution without Conda, or must I go with that environment instead? Thanks beforehand for any help possible!

There's a chance VS Code isn't using the venv even though it's been created. If that's the case, this question might be of interest to you.

The question title says ModuleNotFoundError but the error message in the question says OSError.  Which is it?

This question is similar to: OSError: [WinError 126] module could not be found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hello, this may be because torch is not installed in the interpreter you are using. You can open the command panel with the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P. Type select interpreter to pick the right one for your needs. Try activating the virtual environment with ./venv/scripts/activate and then install torch with pip install torch. Give this a try and see if it resolves the issue.

Switch to old version of pytorch. That should work
pip uninstall pytorch
pip install torch==2.3.1

Thanks for the help and as user1188867 commented it probably has to do with the specific pytorch version 2.4.0
So you could run an older version or you can download "visual studio c/c++ community 2022" to fix the dependency error.
Here is the video which showed me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ky896Qp1k8
